# PDF with div element from different HTML pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pdf

I develop an interface in javascript an PHP.
I work on a project in order to create a PDF report. I have severals pages in my interface like 'FRUITS', 'VEGETABLES', 'FISH', 'MEAT' ...

My final purpose is to have one PDF with information of each pages.
For now, I made a PDF of each page and I want to merge them in order to have just one PDF.The problem with this method is that some page contains just a little table (3/4 rows). And my fear is to have 'large white space' between the different section in my final PDF.

Is anyone know a better method to have a 'clean' final PDF ? Or a plugin to help me contatenate PDF ?

Comment: Well, don't create separate documents, but collect the information and create a single document so that you do not have page breaks.

Comment: And do you know some way to do that properly ?

Comment: Use MPDF as a library and before creating the final PDF, merge your tables !